# TideSDK Notifications in OSX Lion 10.7.5

Tags: tidesdk

I started using the tideSDK for a simple desktop application. Im using the notification api. This works on Windows platforms but not on my OSX Lion 10.7.5.

This is the notification code from the TideSDK docs [tideSDK docs](http://tidesdk.multipart.net/docs/user-dev/generated/#!/api/Ti.Notification)

```
doSomething = () ->
    alert "nice!"

notification = Ti.Notification.createNotification(
    title: "Notification from App"
    message: "Click here for updates!"
    timeout: 10
    callback: doSomething
    icon: "app://img/icon.png"
)
notification.show()
```

SO like a said this works on Windows, so the code seems to be correct, but not on OSX. Any ideas ?

Im using version 1.4.2 of the developer SDK, according to what I read it supposed to work with Growl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Harry, I'm not too familiar with CoffeeScript, but the following code works for me in 10.7.5 and 10.8.4 - it seems similar to what you have:

```
function showNotify(title, message) {
  var notification = Ti.Notification.createNotification({
    'title': title || 'No Title',
    'message': message || 'No Message',
    'timeout': 10
  });
  notification.show();
}

showNotify("The Title", "The Message");
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks, i saw that I turned of growl notification.. lol, stupid me. so it was working all the time